# EXEC stored procedure with flexible parameter for "select count(*)..." and sending an eMail

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I want to write a stored procedure to send an e-mail when the `select count(*)` value is bigger than the value `Menge`.

This stored procedure should be used flexible due the params for more tables and/or "where criteria"

Unfortunately I get this error and I am not able to fix it :(

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_eMail_Test3, Line 23
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select count(*) from test where not [sys_completed] is null' to data type int.

Can you help me?

My stored procedure:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_eMail_Test3]
 @recordCount as int = 0, 
 @FileN as varchar(max) =null,
 @DatSubj as varchar(20) =null,
 @DatFile as varchar(20) =null,
 @SQL_Count as varchar(max) =null,

 @MySQL as varchar(max)=null,
 @MyTable as varchar(max)=null,
 @MyWhere as varchar(max)=null,

 @Menge as int = 0,

 @eMail_TO varchar(max) =null,
 @eMail_Subject varchar(max) =null,
 @eMail_Body varchar(max) =null

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;     
    set @MySQL = 'select count(*) from ' +@MyTable + ' where ' + @MyWhere 
    set @SQL_Count = @MySQL 
    set @recordCount = convert(int, @SQL_Count ) -- <<--this is the error

    IF (@recordCount > @Menge)  
    begin           
        -- variablen zuweisung
        set @DatSubj =  CONVERT(varCHAR(20),  GETDATE() ,120) --datum fürs subject
        set @DatFile =  replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 120), ':','_') --datum für filename
        set @FileN ='Eska_Report_' + @DatFile +'.csv' --filename

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @body_format = 'HTML',
            @profile_name = 'testmailprofile',
            @recipients = @eMail_TO,         
            @subject =  @eMail_Subject ,
            @Body = @eMail_Body  ,
            @query = 'SET NOCOUNT ON;
                        select * from Test where sys_gueltig = ''Y'' 
                        and not sys_completed is null  ',
         @attach_query_result_as_file = 1       , 
         @query_attachment_filename= @FileN     , 
         @query_result_separator = ';'      ,
         @query_result_no_padding= 1,       
         @exclude_query_output =1,      
         @append_query_error = 1,   
         @query_result_header =1
    end    
END
```

I call the SP in this way

```
exec sp_eMail_Test3
    @Menge = 0,
    @eMail_TO = 'testuser@test.xx' ,
    @eMail_Subject = 'test3 ',
    @eMail_Body = 'Hallo, das ist ein Test',
    @MyTable ='test'    ,
    @MyWhere = 'not [sys_completed] is null'
```

In the future I want to call the stored procedure via ADO conenct in VBA

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel obliged to advise you that passing variables into dynamic strings like this leaves you open to SQL injections.  This is a bad practice, and generally frowned upon unless very strictly controlled.

That said...

Change your @MySQL from varchar to nvarchar.

Then try changing this:

```
set @MySQL = 'select count(*) from ' +@MyTable + ' where ' + @MyWhere 
set @SQL_Count = @MySQL 
set @recordCount = convert(int, @SQL_Count ) -- <<--this is the error
```

To this:

```
set @MySQL = 'select @recordCount=count(2) from ' + @MyTable + ' where ' + @MyWhere 
exec sp_execute @MySQL, N'@recordCount int OUTPUT', @recordCount=@recordCount OUTPUT
```

Comment: Hi JiggsJedi, thank you so much vor your help. I changed `sp_Execute` to `sp_Executesql` after getting an error, but now its work really fine!

I know and understand your Security Notice, i´ll allow only 2 users to execute the SP .

My target was to have only 1 SP for counting several tables instead of having "hundreds" :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an error because:

```
set @recordCount = convert(int, @SQL_Count )
```

is attempting to convert your SQL statement (`select blah blah`) from a string to an int.

Try executing `Select @@ROWCOUNT;` after you have executed the stored procedure