# Stored procedere: flexible param for operator on 'IF @recordCount <= @Menge'

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I hope someone can me help again, regarding to my [solved stored procedure problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706198/exec-stored-procedure-with-flexible-parameter-for-select-count-and-sendi)

Is there any chance to make the operator ">" flexible?

Right now my stored procedure works very fine and I will get an eMail when the record count is bigger than the param `Menge`.

The code is this:

```
@Menge as int = 0,  
@recordCount as int = 0,

set @MySQL = 'select @recordCount=count(2) from ' + @MyTable + ' where ' + @MyWhere 
exec sp_execute @MySQL, N'@recordCount int OUTPUT', @recordCount=@recordCount OUTPUT

IF @recordCount > @Menge    
begin
    ...
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
```

Now I want to make `>` flexible to get an e-mail when the record count is smaller than `menge`

I tried to declare the param but I don't know how to insert it into the `if @recordcount > @Menge` line :(

```
@OpInd as char(1) = null
```

I would call the stored procedure with

```
exec sp_eMail_Test3
        @Menge = 0,
        @eMail_TO = 'testuser@test.xx' ,
        @eMail_Subject = 'test3 ',
        @eMail_Body = 'Hallo, das ist ein Test',
        @MyTable ='test'    ,
        @MyWhere = 'not [sys_completed] is null'
        @OpInd = '<'
```

If I try `IF @recordCount +  @OpInd + @Menge` then I get the error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'begin'.

Hopefully you understand my Target and can help me.

If necessary I need to build a 2nd stored procedure :( one for "<" and one for ">"

Best regards Ralf

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: oh! I am very thankful to you for this information. didnt noticed this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your operand to `<>`

```
IF @recordCount <> @Menge    
begin
    ...
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
```

There are only 3 possible operands you want to deal with. `>`, `<`, and `=`. Since you want an email if it's `>` or if it's `<` then just send the email when it's not `=`.

Another way would to repeat your code.

```
IF (@recordCount > @Menge or @recordCount < @Menge)    
begin
    ...
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
```

If you are trying to make it either `>` or `<` then you can use DynamicSQL. Something like...

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 
'IF ' + cast(@recordCount as varchar(16)) + ' ' + @OpInd + ' ' + cast(@Menge as varchar(16)) + '     
begin
    ...
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail'

EXEC(@sql)
```